# Is there any OIDs standard for NAS in MIB tree?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

I'm looking for OIDs for NAS in MIB tree. Is there any standard for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this

http://www.oidview.com/mibs/24681/NAS-MIB.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is specific OIDs of  QNAP SYSTEMS. I'm looking for standard OIDs for NAS. Maybe it's not exist